# Apply function to all pairs efficiently

Tags: haskell, vector, fold

I need a second order function `pairApply` that applies a binary function `f` to all unique pairs of a list-like structure and then combines them somehow. An example / sketch:

```
pairApply (+) f [a, b, c] = f a b + f a c + f b c
```

Some research leads me to believe that `Data.Vector.Unboxed` probably will have good performance (I will also need fast access to specific elements); also it necessary for `Statistics.Sample`, which would come in handy further down the line.

With this in mind I have the following, which *almost* compiles:

```
import qualified Data.Vector.Unboxed as U      

pairElement :: (U.Unbox a, U.Unbox b)    
            => (U.Vector a)                    
            -> (a -> a -> b)                   
            -> Int                             
            -> a                               
            -> (U.Vector b)                    
pairElement v f idx el =
  U.map (f el) $ U.drop (idx + 1) v            

pairUp :: (U.Unbox a, U.Unbox b)   
       => (a -> a -> b)                        
       -> (U.Vector a)                         
       -> (U.Vector (U.Vector b))
pairUp f v = U.imap (pairElement v f) v 

pairApply :: (U.Unbox a, U.Unbox b)
          => (b -> b -> b)                     
          -> b                                 
          -> (a -> a -> b)                     
          -> (U.Vector a)                      
          -> b
pairApply combine neutral f v =
  folder $ U.map folder (pairUp f v) where
  folder = U.foldl combine neutral
```

The reason this doesn't compile is that there is no Unboxed instance of a `U.Vector (U.Vector a))`. I have been able to create new unboxed instances in other cases using `Data.Vector.Unboxed.Deriving`, but I'm not sure it would be so easy in this case (transform it to a tuple pair where the first element is all the inner vectors concatenated and the second is the length of the vectors, to know how to unpack?)

My question can be stated in two parts:

- Does the above implementation make sense at all or is there some quick library function magic etc that could do it much easier?
- If so, is there a better way to make an unboxed vector of vectors than the one sketched above?

Note that I'm aware that `foldl` is probably not the best choice; once I've got the implementation sorted I plan to benchmark with a few different folds.

Comment: Since you write 'all unique pairs', what's wrong with `(a, a)`, `(b, b)`, and `(c, c)`? Do you consider `(a, b)` equal to, or different from, `(b, a)`?

Comment: Alright, say unique pairs of different elements

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no way to define a classical instance for `Unbox (U.Vector b)`, because that would require preallocating a memory area in which each element (i.e. each subvector!) has the same fixed amount of space. But in general, each of them may be arbitrarily big, so that's not feasible at all.

It might *in principle* be possible to define that instance by storing only a flattened form of the nested vector plus an extra array of indices (where each subvector starts). [I once briefly gave this a try](https://gist.github.com/leftaroundabout/24427d8f59527c5b31823abd9778b63f); it actually seems somewhat promising as far as immutable vectors are concerned, but a [`G.Vector`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-0.12.0.1/docs/Data-Vector-Generic.html#t:Vector) instance also requires a mutable implementation, and that's hopeless for such an approach (because any mutation that changes the number of elements in one subvector would require shifting everything behind it).

Usually, it's just not worth it, because if the individual element vectors aren't very small the overhead of boxing them won't matter, i.e. often it makes sense to use `B.Vector (U.Vector b)`.

For your application however, I would not do that at all – there's no need to ever wrap the upper element-choices in a single triangular array. (And it would be really bad for performance to do that, because it make the algorithm take *O* (*n*²) memory rather than *O* (*n*) which is all that's needed.)

I would just do the following:

```
pairApply combine neutral f v
 = U.ifoldl' (\acc i p -> U.foldl' (\acc' q -> combine acc' $ f p q)
                                   acc
                                   (U.drop (i+1) v) )
             neutral v
```

This corresponds pretty much to the obvious nested-loops imperative implementation

```
pairApply(combine, b, f, v):
    for(i in 0..length(v)-1):
        for(j in i+1..length(v)-1):
            b = combine(b, f(v[i], v[j]);
    return b;
```

Comment: Ooh, hadn't noticed the existence of `ifoldl`

Answer (score 3):

My answer is basically the same as leftaroundabout's nested-loops imperative implementation:

```
pairApply :: (Int -> Int -> Int) -> Vector Int -> Int
pairApply f v = foldl' (+) 0 [f (v ! i) (v ! j) | i <- [0..(n-1)], j <- [(i+1)..(n-1)]]
 where n = length v
```

As far as I know, I do not see any performance issue with this implementation.

Non-polymorphic for simplicity.

Comment: Well, I do see a potentially huge performance issue with this... namely, the _O_ (_n_ ²) _list_ you build up before folding over the values. And indeed, without optimisations, [your code runs three times slower than mine](https://gist.github.com/leftaroundabout/6e746cc6b2787a3c9f209e32740547b9). However, and that surprised me, with `ghc-8.2 -O2`, it actually takes only 60% as long as mine does! GHC sure does a great job at fusing control-flow lists to tight loops. I'm still not sure I'd prefer this solution, because this kind of optimisation isn't known to be very reliable.

Comment: Ah, and: your code is faster yet when you replace `!` with [`unsafeIndex`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-0.12.0.1/docs/Data-Vector-Unboxed.html#v:unsafeIndex).

Comment: Upon further testing, I think the performance differences are mostly due to an optimisation regression in GHC-8.2. With GHC-7.10, both versions (yours with `unsafeIndex`) run within 10% of the C reference implementation.

Comment: Reading [this article](https://wiki.haskell.org/Foldr_Foldl_Foldl%27), I thought my code will not build up O(n^2) list by using `foldl'`. But I may be wrong. Thank you anyway for your comment and investigation.

Comment: Indeed your implementation doesn't build up an _O_ (_n_ ²) list... or indeed any list at all, but that's just because GHC optimises it away. You can't generally rely on this – the list is defined in your source code after all. At best, you could count on the garbage collector to reclaim the beginning of the list before the end is processed, but that's still not exactly great performance-wise.